# Convert Factors into Scaled Values

Tags: r

I have team standings data where a column has entries of the form 'Xth of Y'. I need to convert these to numerical values on a 0 to 1 scale where 1st is 1, last is 0, and the remainder occur on a linear scale. I have considered strsplit(), but don't know what to do about some being '1st', some '2nd', etc. To give an example, my data looks like

```
x = as.factor(c('2nd of 6', '5th of 5', '4th of 5', '3rd of 5', '5th of 5', '4th of 7'))
```

Note: '2nd of 6' should convert to 0.8 and not 0.6666667

Comment: Do you need `scale(as.numeric(factor(x, levels = rev(unique(x)))))`  or may be `v1 <- as.numeric(factor(x, levels = rev(unique(x)))); v1/max(v1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract the numbers from the string, split them and create a sequence between 0 and 1 whose length is decided by 2nd number and subset the first number from that sequence.

```
sapply(strsplit(sub("^(\\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th) of (\\d+).*", "\\1-\\2", x), "-"), 
   function(x)  1 - seq(0, 1, length.out = as.integer(x[2]))[as.integer(x[1])])

#[1] 0.80 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.00 0.50
```

Comment: This almost gets me there, but I'm wanting it to break the interval down evenly so that something like '1st of 6' is 1, '2nd of 6' is 0.8, '3rd of 6' is 0.6, etc. This code gives me '1st of 6' as 0.833.

Comment: @ToddBurus How do you get `2nd of 6` as 0.8? Currently I'm doing `1 - (2/6)` which gives you 0.667.

Comment: I'm not getting '2nd of 6' as 0.8, but that's what I need. I want it so that the 'Xth of 6' values get spread evenly across the whole interval 0 to 1, where '6th of 6' is 0 and '1st of 6' is 1.

Comment: If I alter the last line to `1 - ((as.integer(m1[, 1]) -1)/(as.integer(m1[, 2]) -1))` I get what I want, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: @ToddBurus I see what you mean now. You could also use the one you suggested or see the update where I do it using `seq` function.

Comment: Thank you. I thought seq() would be useful, but couldn't quite make it work.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

The OP didn't mention the expected output previously.  So, we are changing the output based on the comments on the other post.

```
df1 <- read.csv(text= gsub("\\D+", ",", x), header = FALSE)
1 - unlist(Map(function(x, y) seq(0, 1, length.out = y)[x], df1$V1, df1$V2))
#[1] 0.80 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.00 0.50
```

#### Old

We can use `base R` to do this in a single line

```
1- Reduce(`/`, read.csv(text= gsub("\\D+", ",", x), header = FALSE))
#[1] 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.2000000 0.4000000 0.0000000 0.4285714
```

---

Or with `strsplit`

```
m1 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), "\\D+"), as.numeric)
1 - m1[1,]/m1[2,]
```

---

Or with `fread`

```
library(data.table)
fread(text=gsub("\\D+", ",", x))[, 1- Reduce(`/`, .SD)]
#[1] 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.2000000 0.4000000 0.0000000 0.4285714
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>%
   str_replace("\\D+", ",") %>% 
   tibble(col1 = .) %>% 
   separate(col1, into = c('col1', 'col2'), convert = TRUE) %>% 
   reduce(`/`) %>%
    -1 *-1
#[1] 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.2000000 0.4000000 0.0000000 0.4285714
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. I apologize for any confusion.